# How can I write Dto Model conversion more easily in C#? (Mapping)

Tags: c#, oop, mapping

I have a product list query that I wrote under normal conditions. I have created a mapper for this query and I can use it as follows.

```
        public IActionResult Index()
        {
            // use normal selecting
            var productList = _context.Products.Select(s => new ProductDto
            {
                Id = s.Id,
                CreateTime = s.CreateTime,
                Title = s.Title,
                Description = s.Description
            }).ToList();

            // use my mapper
            var productListMap = _context.Products
                .ToMap<Product, ProductDto>().ToList();

            return View();
        }
```

On simple data types it works just fine as long as the type and name are the same. But it cannot convert complex types (classes and models).

I thought it would be a nice idea to specify it as a parameter at the time of writing, so that it gets the job done. So I want a layout like below.

```
        public IActionResult Index()
        {
            // what i'm doing now
            var productList = _context.Products.Select(s => new ProductDto
            {
                Id = s.Id,
                CreateTime = s.CreateTime,
                Title = s.Title,
                Description = s.Description,
                Features = s.Features.ToMap<Feature, FeatureDto>().ToList(),
                Images = s.Images.ToMap<Image, ImageDto>().ToList()
            }).ToList();

            // i want to do
            var productListMap = _context.Products
                .ToMap<Product, ProductDto>(p => p.Features, p.Images).ToList();

            return View();
        }
```

What do I need to change/add in the mapper class below to make it easy to use this way?

```
    public static class Mapper
    {
        public static IEnumerable<TDestination> ToMap<TSource, TDestination>(this IEnumerable<TSource> sourceList)
        {
            return sourceList.Select(source => source.ToMap<TSource, TDestination>());
        }

        public static TDestination ToMap<TSource, TDestination>(this TSource source)
        {
            if (source == null) return default;
            var entityProperties = source.GetType().GetProperties();
            var dtoInstance = Activator.CreateInstance<TDestination>();

            for (int i = 0; i < entityProperties.Length; i++)
            {
                var currentPropertyName = entityProperties[i].Name;
                var value = GetPropertyValue(source, currentPropertyName);
                if (dtoInstance.GetType().GetProperty(currentPropertyName) == null)
                    continue;
                try { dtoInstance.GetType().GetProperty(currentPropertyName).SetValue(dtoInstance, value); }
                catch (Exception ex) { /* Nothing */ }
            }
            return dtoInstance;
        }

        public static object GetPropertyValue(object source, string propName)
        {
            if (source == null) throw new ArgumentException("Value cannot be null.", nameof(source));
            if (propName == null) throw new ArgumentException("Value cannot be null.", nameof(propName));
            var prop = source.GetType().GetProperty(propName);
            return prop != null ? prop.GetValue(source, null) : null;
        }
   }
```

Comment: Instructions on writing a custom mapper library from scratch really don't fit well into a StackOverflow post.  Consider looking through the source code for some popular C# mappers to learn how it might be done.

Comment: Actually, I wrote to ask questions, not to give instructions. Judging by the title, I think you misunderstood. I will fix it.